# Tagging Whole Word Based on the First Character in a Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to tag and highlight a whole word based on the first character. In the example below I'm searching for hashtags "#". I want to tag and highlight the subsequent characters until the next space. So the characters "#hashtag" should all be highlighted blue. The code below finds the hashtags and highlights them blue but not the subsequent characters. I assume the problem is that I'm not using `"wordend"` correctly in `self.text_box.tag_add("hashtag{}".format(x), self.index, self.index + "wordend")` but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

According to effbot.org

> “wordstart” and “wordend” moves the index to the beginning (end) of
>   the current word. Words are sequences of letters, digits, and
>   underline, or single non-space characters.
>   http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Any pointers welcome.

Here is some sample code that replicates the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as St

    class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.text = "random text\nrandom text\n#hashtag random text\n#hashtag"

        self.text_box = St.ScrolledText(self)
        self.text_box.pack()

        self.text_box.insert("1.0", self.text)

        self.index = self.text_box.search("#", "1.0", stopindex=tk.END)
        x = 0
        while self.index != "":
            self.text_box.tag_add("hashtag{}".format(x), self.index, self.index + "wordend")
            self.text_box.tag_configure("hashtag{}".format(x), foreground="blue")
            self.index += "+1c"
            self.index = self.text_box.search("#", self.index, stopindex=tk.END)
            x += 1

main=Main()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the canonical tcl/tk documentation:

> A word consists of any number of adjacent characters that are letters, digits, or underscores, **or a single character that is not one of these**. If the display submodifier is given, this only examines non-elided characters, otherwise all characters (elided or not) are examined.

In your case the character after "3.0" is `#` which is "not one of these", so that single character is considered to be a word, and thus the "wordend" modifier stops after that single character.

If you want a hashtag plus the word following it to be given the tag, your second index should be of the form "*line.char*+1c wordend" (eg: "3.0+1c wordend") so that you look for the end of the word beginning with the first character after the hash, not beginning with the hash itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the `tag.add`line to

```
self.text_box.tag_add("hashtag{}".format(x), self.index, (self.index + "+1c") + " wordend").
```

But I'm not sure why I need to add the extra character to the end index of the `tag.add` command? Can anyone explain?